# Why did the scene cut away without Costigan Jr. answering Dignam's question?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

In *The Departed* (2006), Queenan and Costigan Jr. were seated facing each other while
Dignam stood beside the former, facing the latter:

> Dignam: You got quite the family tree. That maggot Uncle of yours...
> Tommy Costigan, is another goof. He gets busted selling guns...
> to federal officers, among many, many, many other departures...
> from our normative behavior.
>
> Costigan Jr: And what's this got to do with me?
>
> Dignam: **Why are you pretending to be a cop?**

Then scene cuts to Ellerby addresses his agents, who are assembled at a table.

Why did the scene cut away without Costigan Jr. answering Dignam's question?

Comment: Because it's rhetorical?